# Expired cookies in opera

Tags: javascript, cookies, opera

We have encountered interesting behavior of cookies in Opera: we should set `expires` option more than one second in the past to remove cookie. If we do something like:

```
var date = new Date();

date.setTime( date.getTime() - 100 );
cookie('c', 'value', { expires: date });
expect(cookie('c')).toBeNull();
```

Test will be failed. But if we set 1000 instead of 100 it will pass.
But in other browsers all is ok. We use `toUTCString()` method for expires.

What is strange: Opera behavior differs from other browsers. Which behavior is incorrect? Opera or others?

Any thoughts?

P.S. I mean Safari, Chrome and Firefox as other browsers.

Comment: Lots of my questions have no answers at all, or have incorrect answers that cant help others. And dont seems correct to me. If answer is correct I always accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the Date object's toUTCString() method, you will get a value like the following:

```
Wed, 12 Dec 2012 12:41:08 GMT
```

As you see, the smallest unit referenced there is a second. Subtracting 100 milliseconds *might* give you a time one second ago *if* the script runs during the first 99 milliseconds of a second. Most of the time you'll simply be setting a cookie that will expire when the *current* second ends, and IMO Opera is technically right to keep the cookie around for the remainder of that second (and hence the remainder of your script).

(While I think it's the correct way to handle a somewhat ambiguous script, I also think that Opera probably should align its expiration policy with other browsers for compatibility, and I seem to recall that there is a bug in Opera's bug tracker on doing so).

Comment: Okay, thanks, I've thought so too. But answer on your own questions done silly here. :)